# Shifting voltage levels to drive high-side P-channel MOSFET

Tags: h-bridge, mosfet-driver, level-shifting, p-channel

I have an H-bridge with P-channel MOSFETs for the high side and N-channel MOSFETs for the low side.

I am driving a 32 V source. The source is first divided by two capacitors in order to correct the voltage to the CMOS Schmitt trigger gates (16VCC, 0GND).

So the N-channel MOSFETs are driven by 16VCC 0GND and the P-channel MOSFETs need to be driven by 32VCC 16GND.

The question is:

How can I shift the CMOS gates level from 16VCC 0GND to 32VCC 16GND without doing the same logic all over again for the P-channel separately?

Is it possible to simply drive it with a 32 V BJT push-pull (driven by the 16 V) and connecting the P-channel MOSFETs' gates to the 16 V rail? I am wondering if it'll affect the capacitors voltage divider.

Comment: Gate drivers for the very purpose exists.

Comment: I don't see how you can reliably split a 32 VDC source into two 16 V rails with just capacitors. Please provide a circuit diagram.

Comment: I do not  understand word problems how about posting a schematic. I am interested in seeing how you did a voltage divider with capacitors. Also the proper reference point for the gate voltage is the source which is probably not connected to ground. The MOSFET has a +- maximum gate voltage, exceeding that will break it. For a P-Channel MOSFET to turn on the gate has to be negative in reference to the source.